# Can OpenCV line or rectangle functions be textured?

Tags: c++, opencv

Does anyone know a method of drawing textured lines or rectangles using OpenCV?  I know this can be done in OpenGL.

Another alternative would be to draw an image, squashed, stretched and rotated so that overlaid on another image would occupy the same space as a line of a given thickness drawn between two points, as shown below.  I'd like to replace the red line of length *L* and width *w* with the image, squashed and stretched to be of the same length and width, and rotated to fit between the black dots.

What I've seen with OpenCV's image rotation is that it creates a larger image to accomodate the rotated image.  Obviously, this isn't what I want.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You should try [perspective transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpperspective) and look at its [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html?highlight=transform). Note that opencv is a matrix manipulation library. So I think you can only create rectangular images with black pixels (0,0,0) for empty spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at perspective projections.  I had to write a function to blend images using alpha, so I'm thinking that if I put a border of transparent pixels around the edge of the image, when OpenCV expands the image to accommodate the rotation, all the "new" pixels will be transparent as well.  Fortunately, OpenCV handles 4D pixels.

Comment: great idea; you can set alpha channels of unused pixels to full transparency.

Comment: Unless I put in an identity matrix, cv::warpPerspective gives me an all black image. This happens whether I use my BGRA image, or separate it into 4, 1 element/pixel images and recombine them. I could understand distorted garbage out because I'm not computing something correctly, but I always get just plain black pixels.

Comment: You should not "put" anything. First you need to get perspective transformation matrix, [given four input and four output points.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform) Only then, use this matrix inside warpPerspective method.

Comment: Here's how I was screwing up: when I was using warpPerspective, I was making an cvMat _just_ big enough to hold the warped image, but I was translating the points to where they were on the final image.  The result was that the non-black pixels I cared about were outside of the  cvMat I'd made for them. [C. Canberk Baci's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2505590/c-canberk-baci) solution worked.

Comment: Here's the algorithm I used (if @C. Canberk Baci, you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll select it and +1 it) 1) Get 4 points around a box the size you'd like the image stretched/squashed. 2) Rotate that box the angle between the 2 points 3) Move the box points so that all the coordinates are positive 4) Get 4 points around a box that would just fit the image 5) Using the 2 sets points, get the perspective matrix 6) Warp the image into a cv::Mat the same size a the boundingRect of the 1st 4 pts 5) Translate boundingRect to hold the 2 input pts 6) Copy warped image to the boundingRect area

Comment: I don't think you need all of this. Use big size for output canvas. I mean, use warpPerspective with high dsize and you will be OK. Another way, create borders and transform after then. I would like to get that +1 when I post these solutions as a well commented code :)

Comment: Combining the warped image with the background image is a pixel-per-pixel operation on the CPU, so I was trying to limit size of the warped image.  I'd post code, but I'm not sure if our contract with the client allows it.